# My webcam Logitech C525 is not focusing on MacOS

Tags: webcam

My Logitech C525 webcam is a bit old, I give you, but it says it supports macOS up to the latest version and also have some installs on the [official site](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-in/articles/360024689894--Downloads-HD-Webcam-C525).

The problem is that it's not "autofocusing", so everything looks kind of blurry. If I put my hand VERY CLOSE, then you can see it very detailed. It was working fine with my Windows 10 machine, so I can only guess I am missing some sort of driver or software or setting here in MacOS to make it work.

I'm running MacOS Monterey 12.0.1.

Comment: Is it **still** working fine on another machine?

Comment: It is. It's just on my Mac machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logitech's Mac support was next to non-existent until the past few years, when they've had a good catch up. They claim only basic UVC support via Apple's native drivers for a lot of older cameras - see Logitech FAQ - [UVC webcam support for Mac OS 10.4.9 and later](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-in/articles/360023207634)

There is now a [Logitech Capture](https://www.logitech.com/en-gb/software/capture.html) app released in the past couple of years which does work with my C920, but the C525 isn't mentioned. Might be worth a try, just in case. At least it's free.

Prior to that, I used [Webcam Settings](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/webcam-settings/id533696630?mt=12) for many years. The info does mention the C525 specifically, but it doesn't look like it's been updated in a couple of years & I've never run it on Big Sur or Monterey, so idk if it's still OK. I'd check Logi's own app first.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll give it a go!

Comment: Capture doesn't support the new M1 chip